# Github API get the last commit for every repository with a search term response

Tags: python, json, git, python-requests, github-api

I'm working on a project using Python(3.6) in which I have implemented GitHub JSON APIs by using the Python's requests package.I'm getting the list of public repos for a specific serach term provided by user.It's providing a response object which includes information about repos but I need to get the last commit  infor of every repo, how can I get this info from response object from Github api.

Here's how I have implemented this:

```
class GhNavigator(CreateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    term = request.GET.get('search_term')
    username = 'arycloud'
    token = 'API_TOKEN'
    login = requests.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=' + term, auth=(username, token))
    response = login.json()
    print(response)

    return render(request, 'navigator/template.html', {'response': response, 'term': term})
```

Here's a sample response:

```
{'total_count': 4618, 'incomplete_results': False, 'items': [{'id': 6750871, 'name': 'arrow', 'full_name': 'crsmithdev/arrow', 'owner': {'login': 'crsmithdev', 'id': 1596037, 'avatar_url': 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/1596037?v=4', 'gravatar_id': '', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/users/crsmithdev', 'html_url': 'https://github.com/crsmithdev', 'followers_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/crsmithdev/followers', 'following_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/crsmithdev/following{/other_user}', 'gists_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/crsmithdev/gists{/gist_id}', 'starred_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/crsmithdev/starred{/owner}{/repo}', 'subscriptions_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/crsmithdev/subscriptions', 'organizations_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/crsmithdev/orgs', 'repos_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/crsmithdev/repos', 'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/crsmithdev/events{/privacy}', 'received_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/crsmithdev/received_events', 'type': 'User', 'site_admin': False}, 'private': False, 'html_url': 'https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow', 'description': 'Better dates & times for Python', 'fork': False, 'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow', 'forks_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/forks', 'keys_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/keys{/key_id}', 'collaborators_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/collaborators{/collaborator}', 'teams_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/teams', 'hooks_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/hooks', 'issue_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/issues/events{/number}', 'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/events', 'assignees_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/assignees{/user}', 'branches_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/branches{/branch}', 'tags_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/tags', 'blobs_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/git/blobs{/sha}', 'git_tags_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/git/tags{/sha}', 'git_refs_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/git/refs{/sha}', 'trees_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/git/trees{/sha}', 'statuses_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/statuses/{sha}', 'languages_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/languages', 'stargazers_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/stargazers', 'contributors_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/contributors', 'subscribers_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/subscribers', 'subscription_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/subscription', 'commits_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/commits{/sha}', 'git_commits_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/git/commits{/sha}', 'comments_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/comments{/number}', 'issue_comment_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/issues/comments{/number}', 'contents_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/contents/{+path}', 'compare_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/compare/{base}...{head}', 'merges_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/merges', 'archive_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/{archive_format}{/ref}', 'downloads_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/downloads', 'issues_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/issues{/number}', 'pulls_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/pulls{/number}', 'milestones_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/milestones{/number}', 'notifications_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/notifications{?since,all,participating}', 'labels_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/labels{/name}', 'releases_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/releases{/id}', 'deployments_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsmithdev/arrow/deployments', 'created_at': '2012-11-18T20:23:27Z', 'updated_at': '2018-05-24T11:23:14Z', 'pushed_at': '2018-05-21T09:03:24Z', 'git_url': 'git://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow.git', 'ssh_url': 'git@github.com:crsmithdev/arrow.git', 'clone_url': 'https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow.git', 'svn_url': 'https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow', 'homepage': 'https://arrow.readthedocs.org', 'size': 1454, 'stargazers_count': 4999, 'watchers_count': 4999, 'language': 'Python', 'has_issues': True, 'has_projects': True, 'has_downloads': True, 'has_wiki': True, 'has_pages': True, 'forks_count': 416, 'mirror_url': None, 'archived': False, 'open_issues_count': 123, 'license': {'key': 'other', 'name': 'Other', 'spdx_id': None, 'url': None}, 'forks': 416, 'open_issues': 123, 'watchers': 4999, 'default_branch': 'master', 'permissions': {'admin': False, 'push': False, 'pull': True}, 'score': 126.08792}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Get the last commit from multiple repositories

Use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to perform your search request and get the most recent commit using `history(first: 1)` when iterating the repository. The graphQL query :

```graphql
{
  search(query: "language:python", type: REPOSITORY, first: 100) {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          defaultBranchRef {
            target {
              ... on Commit {
                history(first: 1) {
                  nodes {
                    message
                    committedDate
                    authoredDate
                    oid
                    author {
                      email
                      name
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22language%3Apython%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20defaultBranchRef%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A%201)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20committedDate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20authoredDate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20author%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

In [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```
import json
import requests

access_token = "YOUR_TOKEN"

query = """
{
  search(query: "language:python", type: REPOSITORY, first: 100) {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          defaultBranchRef {
            target {
              ... on Commit {
                history(first: 1) {
                  nodes {
                    message
                    committedDate
                    authoredDate
                    oid
                    author {
                      email
                      name
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
    }
  }
}
"""

data = {'query': query.replace('\n', ' ')}
headers = {'Authorization': 'token ' + access_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post('https://api.github.com/graphql', headers=headers, json=data)
print(json.loads(r.text)['data']['search']['edges'])
```

You will then need to go through pagination with the cursor value specifying `after: "END_CURSOR_VALUE"` if `hasNextPage` is true. [check this](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/)

#### Get the last commit from a single repository

You can use [list commits on a repository API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) and only return the first element with `per_page=1` since the first is the most recent one. If you don't specify the `sha` parameter it will take the default branch :

https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/commits?per_page=1

Using [Rest API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/) :

```
import requests 
repo = 'torvalds/linux'

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/{0}/commits?per_page=1'.format(repo))

commit = r.json()[0]["commit"]

print(commit)
```

And if you want to use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), you can do the following :

```
import json
import requests

access_token = "YOUR_TOKEN"

query = """
{
  repository(owner: "torvalds", name: "linux") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 1) {
            nodes {
              message
              committedDate
              authoredDate
              oid
              author {
                email
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

data = {'query': query.replace('\n', ' ')}
headers = {'Authorization': 'token ' + access_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post('https://api.github.com/graphql', headers=headers, json=data)
print(json.loads(r.text)['data']['repository']['defaultBranchRef']['target']['history']['nodes'][0])
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?payload=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22torvalds%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22linux%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20defaultBranchRef%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A%201)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20committedDate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20authoredDate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20author%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Hi @Bertrand, I need to grab the last commit for all repositories for a specific search query parameter as in my code above. How can I achieve that in this scenario?

Comment: Can you integrate it with my code, please! because it's not understandable to me as a beginner.

Answer (score -1):

You can also consider the [last push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent): that would represent the last and most recent commit done (on any branch), pushed by a user to this repo.

Comment: Hi @sachin, Can you integrate it with my code, please! because it's not understandable to me as a beginner.